# debugging "connection refused" in AWS EC2 ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I had a working EC2 ubuntu instance (t1.micro) connected through an elastic IP, using an Amazon key pair for a passwordless ssh connection. After running fsck like the terminal suggested (wrong move, I know now), the system rebooted and I keep getting "Network Error: Connection Refused" when trying to connect via ssh.
I managed to attach the instance's volume to an alternative instance, but I could not see what was wrong.
I also tried "ssh -vvv" from an Ubuntu laptop, but got no useful output.
Is there a log I can look at to see why ssh is refusing my connection? 
Is there an alternative way I could debug this?

Comment: The logs are in /var/log.

Comment: Thanks, but which log to look at? I tried auth.log but without success.

Comment: @YuvalF `auth.log` is not interesting in this scenario because the error message you get indicate that the daemon you would connect to has not even started yet. Instead look for `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Thanks @kasperd. Eventually I bypassed this by creating a new instance. I will keep your suggestion in mind should this happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you did everything right. Did you do an fsck while the volume was mounted from another instance? Perhaps there's just something wrong with the filesystem.

Apparently there's a ec2-get-console-output command now: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ec2-clt.pdf

I've never used it. But it if you could see the console, you'd hopefully see what's wrong.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I will try fsck from another instance, and will look for the console output.